# Unable to load DLL '....dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unmanaged

I just inherited this web site project and I've worked out the kinks.  I got it to work in debug mode where I was able to successfully log in all the way the first time, but now every successive time, I've gotten a TypeInitializationException which the inner exception says, "Unable to load DLL 'WebUnmanagedApi.dll': the specified module could not be found.

[image]

Well, I actually found the DLL it says it can't find located a few levels down in the packages folder of my project.

[image]

I wasn't sure why it couldn't find it so I decided to try and add a reference to it to see if that would help, but I received the following error message: "A reference to '.....dll' could not be added.  No type libraries were found in the component".  I figured out that I couldn't directly reference it because it was unmanaged code and wasn't a COM object (no type library).  I'm still unsure what to do to resolve it.  There wasn't any changes (code or otherwise) between the first attempt when it worked and the second when I started getting this error.  I figure the DLL needs to be copied somewhere or something needs to be set somewhere so it can be found.  I tried just copying it to the bin directory and it still didn't load.  What do I need to do to resolve this?  Thanks for your help.

Just wanted to add the line of code causing the error just in case it would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Make sure the project is being built to the same configuration as the DLL in question (x86/x64).

Comment: I checked the properties and it's being built to "Any CPU"; that's the only option in the dropdown list.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: You can click 'configuration manager' in that dropdown and set it up to build to x86 or x64 quite easily. You can probably use something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the DLL

Comment: Pretty sure DLL is x86, but downloaded Dependency Walker, opened DLL, & DW shows error on files it can't find.  Files are located in a separate package than DLL in question.  Any ideas?  That may not be an issue in regards to the project though.  Anyway, in Configuration Manager, I assume I select New in active solution platforms.  Then type 'x86' for the new platform in the New Solution Platform window?  I also probably don't want to copy the settings from 'Any CPU', correct?  Thanks.

Comment: You generally do want to copy the settings actually, it's the easiest way to change the configuration, it won't actually copy the settings pertaining to x86/x64, it'll still build to the new one you select. If everything is building to the correct platform, I would try closing Visual Studio, navigate to: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files  and delete the files in those `Temporary` folders. Also open a run box and type `%temp%` and delete everything in there.

Comment: After that, open VS again, clean the solution, and 'Rebuild'. I know this sounds weird but IIS Express is prone to getting confused with DLLs and what not, sometimes referencing old/wrong assemblies in these temporary directories.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your suggestions to see if that works & will holla back.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: After creating the new x86 platform, shouldn't I be able to select it next to my project in the configuration windows?  It only shows at the top in the Active Solution Platform dropdown.

Comment: Yes beside where you select Debug/Release, you should be able to select Any CPU, x86, x64 etc.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but 'Any CPU' is still the only option in the platform dropdown on the line of my project.  In the dropdown at the top of the window, it's selectable.

Comment: Oh, you have to create the new platforms in the Configuration Manager, `Type or select the new platform`: x86 or x64, `Copy settings from`: Any CPU, `Create new project platforms`: checked.

Comment: I didn't check the 'Create new project platforms' box so do I need to delete the first one and do it again?

Comment: Hey, it won't let me check the create new project platforms checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what that's about, make sure you're always running VS as administrator also.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Yes, I am running VS as an administrator.